# C how to read input separated by commas

Tags: c, string, file-io, line

I want to read the following input into scanf:

```
10 0 y
2
2, 80, 40, 0
```

This should be ready by scanf from a separate file.

I can get the first two lines without the commas by just doing the following:

```
scanf("%d %d %c %d", a1, a2, a3, c1, a4);
```

How would I be able to read the third line that is separated by commas and store those in my variables?

Comment: That's not your real `scanf` example, is it?

Answer (score 8):

You can just include the commas in a `scanf` format string:

```
int blinky, pinky, inky, clyde;
scanf("%d, %d, %d, %d", &blinky, &pinky, &inky, &clyde);
```

Here's a complete example based on your question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a1, a2, a4;
    int blinky, pinky, inky, clyde;
    char c3;

    scanf("%d %d %c %d %d, %d, %d, %d", &a1, &a2, &c3, &a4, &blinky, &pinky, &inky, &clyde);
    printf("%d %d %c\n%d\n%d, %d, %d, %d\n", a1, a2, c3, a4, blinky, pinky, inky, clyde);

    return 0;
}
```

And to build and test:

```
$ cat input 
10 0 y
2
2, 80, 40, 0
$ make example
cc     example.c   -o example
$ ./example < input
10 0 y
2
2, 80, 40, 0
```

Comment: +1. I wish I could up-vote this again just for the var-names =P

Comment: scanf("%d %d %c %d %d, %d, %d, %d", &penalty, &numberDropped, &stat, &numOfAssignments, &assignmentNumber, &studentScore, &weight, &daysLate);  This is what I did and I can print everything except for the last 3 integer values. 4 80 and 0.

Comment: @user2817240, then you're doing something else wrong.  I'll put a complete example in my answer.

Comment: Ok it worked now. Thanks a lot for your help Carl. I just had to add a space in front of the first %d or else it wouldn't work. You just have to be really specific.

Comment: To clarify my last comment, I DIDN'T need a space before the first %d. I originally had one, which was messing up my program. I removed it and followed what you wrote and it worked.